# Do oppositely charged fused spheres align in electric fields

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, thermodynamics, electrostatics, temperature

Molecules in solids get polarized and the resulting dipoles align with the external bias field. Can this be done with lightweight spheres that are oppositely charge on their surfaces? Like surfaces that are contact electrified. If a powder made of such oppositely charged fused spheres is placed in a bias field, will each individual particle (two oppositely charged fused spheres) align themselves? If clumping becomes an issue, I guess we could vibrate them lightly while in the bias field.

[image]

Comment: Every dipole,- no matter how it is constructed,- has [dipole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_dipole_moment) in the electric field. The only question is,- Does this electric field has enough strength for injecting enough torque based on $\boldsymbol {\tau }=\mathbf {p} \times \mathbf {E}$ producing noticeable alignment of the dipole.

Comment: Really? Does this mean that this powder will also have a decrease in entropy, like molecular dipoles have when they align?

Comment: Yes. If torque will be big enough for overcoming any resistance from dipole, then due to drastically reduced number of alignment microstates a dipole can have - entropy will be reduced too.

Comment: And that means the temperature of the powder will decrease too, in adiabatic conditions. Why isn't this used for refrigeration, instead of ferroelectric materials? Vibrate it without bias field so all dipoles randomize. Entropy increases, heat in (cooling). Turn on bias field, vibrate and dipoles align, entropy decreases, heat out.

Comment: I'm not the expert in this area, but in [electrocaloric cooling cycle](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/cms/asset/438476cc-ff67-4f01-8b66-291ef81e2e19/nfg003.gif) as external field is switched-off ferroelectric material goes back to spontaneous polarization itself. While you say, that for randomizing these artificial dipoles one needs vibration, i.e. additional energy, so probably this way is ineffective by energy consumption compared to materials which has spontaneous electric polarization. Anyway, your last comment is more about engineering, instead of Physics.